# Prove A ⊆ (A ⊕ B) ∩ A.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$(A\oplus B) = A^c \cup B $

Then prove or disprove

$ A \subseteq(A\oplus B)\cap  A$

I've tried doing like this:

$A \subseteq  (A^c \cup B) ∩ A$

$A \subseteq  (A^c \cap A) \cup (B \cap A)$

$A \subseteq  \emptyset\cup(B \cap A)$

$A \subseteq  (B \cap A).$

Comment: What does "like the complement" mean? Are these sets or abelian groups or something else?

Comment: these are arbitrary sets

Comment: So $A^c$ IS the complement? You need to use MathJax to typeset your math so this is readable.  And please don't interchange $b$ and $B$.

Comment: Is $\oplus$ meant to be exclusive or?

Comment: Not really, it's a defined operator as $(A\oplus B) = A^c \cup B$

Answer (score 1):

This is false. If you take $B$ to be the empty set and $A$ to be any nonempty set, it reduces to $A \subseteq A \cap A^c = \emptyset$, a contradiction.
Perhaps you meant something else?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your proposition seems incorrect.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, $(A\oplus B)$ is $\text{\{green\}} \cup \text{\{white\}} \cup \text{\{grey\}}$ and $(A\oplus B)\cap A$ is only the grey region. However, $A$ is not included.

For correct reasoning and proposition, it should be:

$A \supseteq  (A^c \cup B) ∩ A$

$\Leftarrow A \supseteq  (A^c \cap A) \cup (B \cap A)$

$\Leftarrow A \supseteq  \emptyset\cup(B \cap A)$

$\Leftarrow A \supseteq  (B \cap A).$